# Creating a table using key/values stored in Chrome storage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, html-table, google-chrome-storage

I'm trying to create a table using JSON in Chrome.sync.storage. Here's what I have in storage-

```
"06-02-2018" : {"end" : "22:04", "start" : "22:04", "tasks" : "hello world"}
"18-02-2018" : {"end" : "1:05", "start" : "2:04", "tasks" : "hello world"}
"22-03-2018" : {"end" : "11:03", "start" : "15:04", "tasks" : "hello world"}
```

Here's what I'm trying to achieve-

```
var storage = chrome.storage.sync;

function generateTable() {
    var table = document.createElement('table');

    storage.get(null, function (items) {

        var allKeys = Object.keys(items);

        // For every date in table,
        for (var i = 0; i < allKeys.length; ++i) {

            var currentKey = allKeys[i];

            var tr = document.createElement('tr');
            storage.get([currentKey], function(result){

                // For every set of keys for a date,
                $.each(result, function(date,details){
                    var td = document.createElement('td');
                    td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(date));
                    tr.appendChild(td);

                    $.each(details, function(key,value){
                        var tdTemp = document.createElement('td');
                        tdTemp.appendChild(document.createTextNode(value));
                        tr.appendChild(tdTemp);
                    });

                    table.appendChild(tr);
                    console.log(tr);
                });

            }); 
        }
    });

    console.log(table);
    document.body.appendChild(table);
}
```

Problem is- Instead of having a single row for each date & 4 cells for each row, the table only has a single row with 12 cells. It looks like it could be due to Asynchronous behavior of chrome storage. Any suggestions?

Comment: You've already all the items from storage (`storage.get(null, function (items) {`), then why you are retrieving all storage keys again (`storage.get([currentKey], function(result){`) ? Is there any specific reason ?

Comment: Ah yes, I'll remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that it fails due to the asynchronous nature of the chrome storage.

What essentially happens is that you append 3 empty table rows to the table, but when the first callback comes back it thinks that the third row is the row to append to, and the same goes for the other two callbacks.

Also using `$.each()` is unnecessary, because you dealing with a simple object literal.

```
var storage = chrome.storage.sync;

function generateTable() {
    var table = document.createElement('table');

    storage.get(null, function (items) {
        for (currentKey of Object.keys(items)) {
            var dateElement = items[currentKey];

            var tableRow = document.createElement('tr');
            tableRow.appendChild(createTableData(currentKey));

            for(elementValue of Object.values(dateElement)){
               tableRow.appendChild(createTableData(elementValue));
            }
            table.appendChild(tableRow); 
        }
        document.body.appendChild(table);
    });
}

function createTableData(value){
    var tableData = document.createElement('td');
    tableData.appendChild(document.createTextNode(value));
    return tableData;
}
```

Now everything is done in the first callback, so everything is synchronous after the storage returns the first time